# How to selectively and securely enable hidden test features in iOS application?

Tags: ios, security, testing

I would like my iOS application to provide a special set of commands for testing only.  I would like these commands to be available only to authorized testers, not to general users.

The iOS application has external connectivity to a secure web site I control, and I can also freely manipulate the iPhones it runs on in test.

How could I decide (programmatically and securely, at startup) whether my app should enable its test mode?

Comment: You said that it has a secure connection to a server right? So I recommend having an extern BOOL in your AppDelegate (since you want it as startup), or the root UIViewController, doesn't make a difference whatsoever, which should be available anywhere. After the secure connection get the NSData from the server, which can be as simple as a string. Then do a simple if statement. Say, if you want testing the string is approved. So `if ([returnedData isEqualToString:@"Approved"] { testing = TRUE; } else { testing = FALSE; }`

Comment: Oh and obviously at the init, or ViewDidLoad, test if it's true or false and act accordingly.

Comment: @isklikas -- how would the server know *which* phone is asking whether it is approved for testing?  Can I get the serial # or something to send in the HTTP request?

Comment: well, if there's a secure connection, you could be using an account that these people will have on your server? So you prompt them to a login screen on your sever. Where they will use an email, a prompted username and a set password. Because Apple doesn't allow anymore access to UDIDs, you need to do it that way.